# Compile C++ in vim

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, neovim, filetype-c++, filetype-c

I want to make a shortcut for compiling C++ file. I use `:map <F5> :!g++ % -o app && ./app <CR>`. How can I edit it to set output file's name, C++ file's name without `.cpp` instead of `app`?

For example I want the name of g++ output file to be `main` when I use `<F5>` when I edit `main.cpp`.

**NOTE: I use neovim 0.6.1**

Comment: Thanks you! This is what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out some related questions: https://vi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfiletype-c%2B%2B%5D+g%2B%2B, https://vi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfiletype-c%2B%2B%5D+compile

A short answer: prefer to use `:make` to build and probably `:terminal` or `:!` to run the program, all of which you can bind maps to.

But if you insist on this particular setup: `:help cmdline-special` and `:help filename-modifiers` give `%:t:r`.